# When ever i am running npm run ng build-hin i am getting below error and build got failed

Tags: angular-cli

```
build": "ng build",
"build-en": "ng build --output-path=dist/en --base-href=.",
"build-hin": "ng build --output-path=dist/hin --configuration=hin --base-href=.",
"build-ar": "ng build --output-path=dist/ar --configuration=ar --base-href=.",
```

my command: **npm run ng build-hin**

Not only hin,but for every language build.

Error:

> Localized bundle generation failed: Call retries were exceeded npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE npm ERR! errno 1 npm ERR! empyreal-iot@0.0.0 build-hin: `ng build --output-path=dist/hin --configuration=hin --base-href=.` npm ERR! Exit status 1 npm ERR! npm ERR! Failed at the empyreal-iot@0.0.0 build-hin script. npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above. npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: npm ERR! C:\Users\devangams\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2020-06-25T15_09_31_671Z-debug.log

---

Comment: Did you find a solution to this? I am hitting the same error..

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question but I was having the same issue on node 10. Updating to node 12 solved the problem for me